# Nginx variable equivalent of: $scheme://$host:$port

Tags: nginx

When redirecting, I want to redirect to the same scheme+host+port as the request, but with a different path. Is there an Nginx variable which is the equivalent of `$scheme://$host:$port`?

For example, when a request for `https://www.some-site.net/login.htm` comes in, it should be redirected to `https://www.some-site.net/login` (e.g. no ".htm").

Is there a variable that consolidates `$scheme://$host:$port`?

Comment: You could use `$scheme://$host:$port`. However, `return 301 /login;` will use the same scheme host and port (unless you've explicitly turned the feature off).

Comment: Wow thanks that is so obvious now that you mention it. Post an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The variables `$scheme://$host:$server_port` are all supported by Nginx and are [documented here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html).

However, you don't necessarily need to use them, as Nginx automatically provides the missing components.

For example, the statement:

```
return 301 /login;
```

will use the same scheme, host and port as the original request by default, unless this behaviour is explicitly overridden by directives such as [`absolute_redirect`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#absolute_redirect),
[`port_in_redirect`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#port_in_redirect), or [`server_name_in_redirect`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name_in_redirect).

Comment: `$port` is not a nginx variable, in fact, is not reported in the linked documentation.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that @Paulecci. Corrected.

Comment: Well, I do have absolute_redirect turned off because I'm using nginx behind a reverse proxy, so `$scheme://$http_host/login` seems to work for me (see `$http_name` in docs)